# Transpose specific rows into columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset that has information like below:

```
Title                         Year                 Revenue (Mi)
---------------------------------------------------------------
Guardians of the Galaxy       2015                   313.13
Split                         2016                   138.0
Sing                          2016                   270.32
Moana                         2015                   248.02
```

I want to convert this piece of data to this form:

```
Title                        2015                      2016
------------------------------------------------------------
Guardians of the Galaxy     313.13
Split                                                 138.02
Sing                                                  270.32
Moana                       248.02
```

How can I convert my data frame to this form ?? I am not getting what should I do in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
out = df.pivot(index='Title', columns='Year', values='Revenue (Mi)').reset_index()
```

Comment: yeah. That's what I wanted. Thanks a lot.